# How to download many levels of web pages in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, asihttprequest, offline-caching

I use ASIWebPageRequest to save the web pages to local disk, but it can only download the page being viewed current. Is there any way to download muti levels of the website such as download the first page and all the second even third level pages linked by it.
Thank you very much!